# Check for circular dependencies

Tags: vba

## Introduction

Sometimes, especially in more complex class structures, I feel uncertain in some way whether undiscovered circular dependencies might exist.

So I thought about how I can easily have their existence checked.

---

## The idea behind

I came up with the idea of using a central place where I automatically register all relevant objects when they are created and remove them when they are destroyed.

If desired/necessary, one can also store context information for each object there, in order to be able to distinguish the object instances during the evaluation.

---

## Weak References

Of course you could use weak references in general, but maybe you can't/won't do that depending on the project.

---

## (De)activate monitoring

Conditional compilation is used for this purpose. This also ensures that the code for productive environments is not affected.

To create a project-wide conditional compilation constant, the VBE's Project Properties dialog must be used:

For `Conditional Compilation Arguments` the variable `MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES` can be specified and set to `0` or `1`.

Example:

```vb
MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES = 1
```

---

## Error handling

Concrete error handling for sure could/should be implemented.

---

## Naming

I have followed here the other day in another question that one thinks about naming conventions.

I did that too and decided for me some time ago to use Pascal Casing (`MyProcedureName`) for object and procedure names and Camel Casing (`myVariableName`) for parameter and variable names.

I always capitalize constants completely and separate words with underscores (`MY_CONSTANT_NAME`).

I always preface comments with `'//`, which is visually more pleasant to me.

To avoid VBA to automatically re-case my literals, I try to find good names to distinguish them and so avoid the need of same literals to be written in different casing.

Sometimes this is not possible, a good example is `value`, which is used like `Value` from some libraries already, so I can't name a variable `value`.

For such special cases like this, I have come to terms with using an actually meaningless 'prefix': `x`. This has no relation to a prefix as such.

The `x` actually only ensures visually that my eyes feel comfortable with the code. This is of course purely subjective, but I feel fine with it.

Examples where I use this 'prefix' are e.g. these:

- `xValue`
- `xIndex`
- `xItem`
- `xResult`

This is the compromise I have arranged with.

---

## The implementation

> CyclicDependenciesMonitor

Important: This class uses `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True`

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type TState
    MonitoredObjects As Collection
End Type

Private this As TState

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Reset
End Sub

'// Reset object monitoring for another run
Public Sub Reset()
    Set this.MonitoredObjects = New Collection
End Sub

'// Add an object for monitoring
Public Sub Add(ByVal objectToMonitor As Object)
    this.MonitoredObjects.Add _
        ObjPtr(objectToMonitor) & " (" & TypeName(objectToMonitor) & ")", _
        CStr(ObjPtr(objectToMonitor))
End Sub

'// This procedure allows to store additional
'// context information if desired for debugging
Public Sub AddContextInformation(ByVal monitoredObject As Object, _
                                 ByVal contextInformation As String)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim xResult As String
    xResult = this.MonitoredObjects(CStr(ObjPtr(monitoredObject)))

    If xResult = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    xResult = xResult & " " & contextInformation

    Remove monitoredObject

    this.MonitoredObjects.Add xResult, CStr(ObjPtr(monitoredObject))
End Sub

'// Remove an object from monitoring
Public Sub Remove(ByVal objectToMonitor As Object)
    this.MonitoredObjects.Remove CStr(ObjPtr(objectToMonitor))
End Sub

'// Determine information from leftover objects
Public Function LeftoverObjects() As String
    LeftoverObjects = TypeName(Me) & " - " & "Objects left over: " & _
        this.MonitoredObjects.Count & vbNewLine

    If this.MonitoredObjects.Count = 0 Then Exit Function

    LeftoverObjects = LeftoverObjects & vbNewLine & _
        "<Memory Adress> (<TypeName>) <Provided context Information>" & vbNewLine & _
        "-----------------------------------------------------------" & vbNewLine

    Dim xItem As Variant
    For Each xItem In this.MonitoredObjects
        LeftoverObjects = LeftoverObjects & xItem & vbNewLine
    Next xItem
End Function
```

---

## Embedding code in user classes

For demonstration I created two user defined classes, one with a possibility to add context data for debugging internally.

> UserClass

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type TState
    SampleStoredObject As Object
End Type

Private this As TState

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.Add Me
    #End If

    '// Place here the code that your class needs in this procedure
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    '// Place here the code that your class needs in this procedure

    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.Remove Me
    #End If
End Sub

'// This is a sample procedure that receives and stores an object
'// to provoke a cyclic dependency
Public Sub SampleStoreObject(ByVal objectToStore As Object)
    Set this.SampleStoredObject = objectToStore
End Sub
```

> AnotherUserClass

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Type TState
    SampleStoredObject As Object
    SampleContextData As String
End Type

Private this As TState

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.Add Me
    #End If

    '// Place here the code that your class needs in this procedure
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    '// Place here the code that your class needs in this procedure

    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.Remove Me
    #End If
End Sub

'// This is a sample procedure that receives and stores an object
'// to provoke a cyclic dependency
Public Sub SampleStoreObject(ByVal objectToStore As Object)
    Set this.SampleStoredObject = objectToStore
End Sub

'// This procedure could have been intentionally created to store contextual information,
'// but it could also be an existing procedure that is now also used for this purpose
Public Sub SampleStoreContextData(ByVal contextData As String)
    this.SampleContextData = contextData

    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.AddContextInformation Me, contextData
    #End If
End Sub
```

---

## Using it

As you can see, the code creates three objects of two different types.

`Object1` and `Object3` then reference each other, causing a cyclic dependency.

After attempting to destroy the objects, existing cyclic dependencies are determined and output.

Commenting out one of these lines prevents the existence of circular dependencies:

```vb
object1.SampleStoreObject object3
object3.SampleStoreObject object1
```

> ClientTestModule

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestObjectMonitoring()
    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.Reset
    #End If

    Dim object1 As UserClass
    Set object1 = New UserClass

    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        '// Add some context data for monitoring
        '// (however, this is not necessary and just for debugging purposes)
        CyclicDependenciesMonitor.AddContextInformation object1, "Foo"
    #End If

    Dim object2 As UserClass
    Set object2 = New UserClass

    Dim object3 As AnotherUserClass
    Set object3 = New AnotherUserClass

    '// The context data for monitoring will be added by a class method of the object
    '// (however, this is also not necessary)
    object3.SampleStoreContextData "Bar"

    '// Provoke a cyclic dependency:
    object1.SampleStoreObject object3
    object3.SampleStoreObject object1

    '// The attempt to destroy the objects by removing the references
    Set object1 = Nothing
    Set object2 = Nothing
    Set object3 = Nothing

    #If MONITOR_CYCLIC_DEPENDENCIES Then
        '// Check whether monitored objects still exist, which have not been destroyed
        Debug.Print CyclicDependenciesMonitor.LeftoverObjects()
    #End If
End Sub
```

---

## Output

```
CyclicDependenciesMonitor - Objects left over: 2

<Memory Adress> (<TypeName>) <Provided context Information>
-----------------------------------------------------------
2357270190368 (UserClass) Foo
2357270190512 (AnotherUserClass) Bar
```

Or in case no cyclic dependency exists:

```
CyclicDependenciesMonitor - Objects left over: 0
```

---

## Questions

What are your thoughts on this?

Is the approach useful/workable?

Do you have any suggestions for improvement?